# Can you get Visual Studio to show an unsigned char[] as an array, and a not string in watch/locals?

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging

Is there anyway in Visual Studio 2022 to show an `unsigned char[32]` as a byte array rather than as a string?  The array may have `'\0'` in which of course stops display.
You can expand, but if you have a few watches then this becomes tedious to scroll.

I've seen the format specifiers page, but not been able to work out how to change it for an array.

Comment: @kkm-still-wary-of-se-promises your edit of my question means it now says the opposite!  I mean I want to know if I can get visual studio to show it as an array not a string. It could possibly be clearer though.

Answer (score 1):

Simple press the arrow ner the symbol in tha watch window.

You can also see object referenced by the pointer as an array by specifying how many elements you want to see.

```
    unsigned char test[] = "ttt\0d";
    unsigned char* test1 = test;
```

[image]

Comment: Yes - but as I said "You can expand, but if you have a few watches then this becomes tedious to scroll." 
It's not so bad with 2 arrays of 5 - but I have 4 arrays of 64 numbers to watch changing

Answer (score 0):

One simple possibility is to use raw memory view:

[image]

Choose the "Memory" tab and type `xx`<kbd>Enter</kbd> into the Address field to visualise the `xx` array.

Unfortunately the `xx` you type into the Address field is immediately transformed into it's address, so that on the next run, you need to type `xx` again.

Comment: Not me but he did not want dump only display as array.

Comment: This is similar to expanding - works well for a single array, but if you have several to watch changing in step and you can't see which is which easily